# A field in the dataset 'Dataset1' has the name" ". Field names must be CLS-compliant identifiers

Tags: c#, sql-server

Im creating a report.rdlc using ReportViewer and I occuring this error.

Comment: Have you got your dataset from sql server? Could you provide the query?

Comment: The error seems quite clear.

Comment: What is CLS-compliant?

Comment: CLS compliant here means the names should be valid in all .NET languages. You seem to have an empty name or maybe one with an embedded space. So, look at the query.

Comment: How can I view the query?

Comment: No idea. It's your report, it must be getting data from somewhere.

Answer (score 4):

If you have the column name in data set like "Customer Name" Change it to "Customer_name" put underscore or Remove Space

Answer (score 0):

**Sol1:**
Changing name of your field according to [CLS Compilance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bhc3fa7f(v=vs.100).aspx) will resolve your issue.

**Sol2:**
Also if you are not using this field in your report and its just appearing in your rdlc due to its use in viewmodel ,then you can just delete it from rdlc and your issue will be resolved.